# What is this time format? How can I convert it to readable format?

Tags: ios, swift, date, datetime, timezone

In my iOS app, I am getting the date format as `20231220T090000` for my calendar event in response. How will I convert this datetime from the date?

How to convert it to `20 Dec 2023, 9 AM`?

I can't figure out the correct date format for it.

Comment: Which one is blocking you. `20231220T090000` to `Date` or `Date` to `20 Dec 2023, 9 AM`? Did you try looking at http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns ?

Comment: That is an [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) date-time in _"basic format"_.  You've maybe seen the more common _"extended format"_, which would be `2023-12-20T09:00:00`.  Note that because there is neither a `Z` nor a numeric offset at the end, this timestamp has an _ambiguous_ local time zone. Thus the _exact_ instant in time would depend on how it is applied.

Answer (score 3):

You need a date formatter to parse the input:

```swift
let parsingFormatter = DateFormatter()
parsingFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
parsingFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss"
```

By the way, you do not specify in what timezone the input string represents. Often it is in GMT/UTC/Zulu, in which case you would also include:

```swift
parsingFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)
```

Note, this input string is likely in a fixed-format and, if so, it is important to set the [`locale`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/dateformatter/1411973-locale) of this date parsing formatter, as shown above, in case the user device is not using a Gregorian calendar.

Anyway, you also need another date formatter to produced your output string:

```swift
let outputFormatter = DateFormatter()
outputFormatter.dateFormat = "d MMM yyyy',' h a"
```

No `locale` or `timeZone` is needed in this second formatter, as you undoubtedly want this output string formatted using the device default settings.

As an aside, we would generally avoid using `dateFormat` for output strings, but rather use `dateStyle` and `timeStyle` instead. (See the distinction between “[user visible](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/dateformatter/#1680045)” and “[fixed format](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/dateformatter/#2528261)” date strings in the `DateFormatter` documentation.) Using date/time styles ensures that the date string is produced in a standard format, and one that is localized in accordance with the device settings, e.g.:

```swift
let outputFormatter = DateFormatter()
outputFormatter.dateStyle = .medium
outputFormatter.timeStyle = .short
```

Or, if you insist on this custom format (e.g., showing hours without minutes), you might consider using a localized date format string:

```swift
let outputFormatter = DateFormatter()
outputFormatter.setLocalizedDateFormatFromTemplate("dMMMyyyyha")
```

Anyway, now that you have your two formatters, you can parse the input and prepare the output string like so:

```swift
let input = "20231220T090000"
if let date = parsingFormatter.date(from: input) {
    let result = outputFormatter.string(from: date)
    …
}
```

Comment: Hey @Rob, quick question, why is generally advisable to avoid using a `dateFormat` for output strings?

Comment: I think dateFormat just supports a specific string format, and dateStyle & timeStyle can support localization.

Comment: Because if it is for the UI, you want it to be localized, shown in the format preferred by the user. E.g. UK users will prefer ”20 Dec 2023“, but US users will prefer “Dec 20, 2023”. By using a “style”, it will honor the settings shown in “Settings” » “General’ » “Language & Region” » “Date Format” (which also shows you what the “short”, “medium”, “long”, and “full” date format styles will produce). See the discussion of “user visible” and “fixed format” date formats in the `DateFormatter` [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/dateformatter/).

Comment: Also, if the user settings prefer a “24 hour” time format (e.g., “14:00” rather than “2:00 pm”), `timeStyle` will honor that setting, too.

Answer (score 1):

In your example, `20231220T090000` represents a date in the following format:

```
yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss
```

And you're trying to turn it into the following format:

```
dd MMM yyyy, h a
```

You can use [`DateFormatter`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/dateformatter) to parse the date from your input string and then re-format it into another date with the target format.

Something like this could achieve what you're looking for:

```swift
let inFormat = DateFormatter()
inFormat.dateFormat = "yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss"

let inDate = inFormat.date(from: "20231220T090000")

let outFormat = DateFormatter()
outFormat.dateFormat = "dd MMM yyyy, h a"

let outString = outFormat.string(from: inDate!)

print(outString) // 20 Dec 2023, 9 AM
```

---

This can help you if you need the date format to be [fixed](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/dateformatter/#overview). If you wish to display this date to a user, you should instead set `.dateStyle` and `.timeStyle` to the `outFormat`.

[Rob's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77788026/11200608) is more detailed and informative.

Comment: Thank you, I edited the answer with that in mind.

Comment: Part of your answer "yyyyMMdd'T'hhmmss" still wrong. There are other issues with your answer like not setting the locale and or timezone of your date formatter. You can read @Rob answer for more details about it